# Image rendering in React with webpack

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to render the images on my React app, but I get "failed to load resource..404 not found" in browser.

As mentionded in App.js file, relative path is not working but importing the image is working. I want to use relative paths, for a different functionality in my application.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Img from './images/test.jpg';

function App() {
   return(
      <div className="App">
         <img src={Img} alt="test" /> //option-1 (this works)
         <img src='./images/test.jpg' alt="test-2" /> //option-2 (this does not work)
      </div>
    );
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
     path: path.join(__dirname,'/dist'),
     filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })
  ],
  module: {
     rules: [
          {
             test: /\.js$/,
             exclude: /node_modules/,
             use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                     presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react']
                  }
             }
         },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
         },
         {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            type: 'asset/resource'
         }
    ]
  }
}
```

My folder structure

```
-node_modules
-src
  -components
  -css
  -images
     -test.jpg
  -App.js
  -index.html
  -index.js
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
```

I have tried to change the image rule in webpack.config.js with following

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: ['file-loader','url-loader']
}
```

but after this change the imported image also stops working.

Comment: It will not work becuase in order to directly add path in image tag images should be under public folder outside src. And then you can directly do <img src='/image/imagename'

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after I moved it to public folder.

Comment: can i post this as answer then you can accept ?

Comment: can you please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work because in order to directly add the path in the image tag images should be under the public folder outside src. And then you can directly do

```
<img src="/images/imageName"/>
```